# How can we detect that we are right after display math mode? (for vertical spacing)

Tags: spacing, equations, plain-tex

I need a "`\smartmedskip`" feature/macro in plain TeX which is in usual identical to `\medskip`, however, if we are right after display math mode, then it should be just "disabled", i.e. it should then behave as `\par` (or `\vskip0pt`).

(I want to use this in a macro that inserts exercises to my exercise list. Now if the last line of an exercise is a math formula, then in sum I get too much space between this and the next exercise.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want that it does nothing whenever it follows another vertical skip:

```
\def\smartmedskip{\par
  \ifdim\lastskip>0pt \else \medskip\fi
}

This will be followed by a {\tt\string\medskip}.

\smartmedskip

This has a displayed formula
$$
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n
$$
\smartmedskip
but the {\tt\string\smartmedskip} does nothing.

This has a displayed formula
$$
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n
$$
\medskip
and we check the difference.

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. This solution does what I want. (In fact, I knew about \lastskip, but I did not know that it indicates \belowdisplayskip, too.)