# How to define this new environment and avoid the hidden errors?

Tags: line-breaking, environments, displaystyle

I want to define a new environment ends with a $\omega$ in newline. But environment like displaymath already start a newline after itself, so I do not start a newline in this case. That is, start a newline only after normal text but not environment. How to make it?

The original definition is as following which starts a newline after environment also.

```
\newenvironment{note}{%
\noindent
\textsc{Note}
\vskip\medskipamount % or other desired dimension
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt % or other desired thickness
\vskip\medskipamount % ditto
\nointerlineskip
}{\mbox{}~\newline\mbox{} \hfill$\Omega$\newline}
```

As suggested by Peter Grill, I define a `\smartsmallskip`. And  as suggested by David, I change the `\newline` to `\par`.

```
\def\smartsmallskip{\par
  \ifdim\lastskip>0pt \else \smallskip\fi
}

\newenvironment{note}{%
\noindent
\textsc{Note}
\vskip\medskipamount % or other desired dimension
\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt % or other desired thickness
\vskip\medskipamount % ditto
\nointerlineskip
}{\smartsmallskip\hfill$\Omega$\par}
```

Is there still some question I should take care of?

Comment: Does [How can we detect that we are right after display math mode? (for vertical spacing)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162147/how-can-we-detect-that-we-are-right-after-display-math-mode-for-vertical-spaci) answer your question?

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks! it does. Should I delete this post?

Comment: why `\newline` and the blank lines from`\mbox{}~` rather than `\par` and vertical space? or better a definition using `\newtheorem` or similar? This version will have very strange behaviour near a page break.

Comment: @EdenHarder: No, don't delete it. This will get marked as a duplicate if it is determined to be one.  This increases the chances of others finding the answer in the future.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much! I update the post, is there still some question I should take care of?

Comment: it's better to use a list environment (as used by \newtheorem) as that takes care of things, as is, there is not control over the space before `Note` the page could break  after the heading before the environment contents (or after the leaders) and the spacing between the rule and first line of text is going to be rather variable due to the `\nointerlineskip` (which means it will be different whether or not there is a capital letter  or accent on the first line of content) the final `\newline` should be a `\par` (most likely).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Many thanks! Could you rewrite the  definition as an answer and explain it in details?

Comment: @EdenHarder Don't forget that in LaTeX there is `\addvspace`, so `\addvspace{\smallskipamount}` is what you need instead of `\smartsmallskip`

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot! But there should be a `\par` before `\addvspace` which add the vspace, it will fail otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want; instead of a `\smallskip` before the last line, I have used a strut next to the Omega (actually, I think there shouldn't be an additional space and the symbol should go at the end of the last line). The line shouldn't be detached from the heading and the body thanks to `\nopagebreak`, the same for the last line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{note}
  {\par\vspace{\topsep}%
   \noindent\textsc{Note}\par\nopagebreak
   \medskip
   \hrule
   \nopagebreak
   \medskip}
  {\par\skip0=\lastskip\nopagebreak
   \hspace*{\fill}\mbox{\ifdim\skip0>0pt \else\rule{0pt}{2ex}\fi$\Omega$}\par
   \vspace{\topsep}}
    \begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{note}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{note}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain about `\mbox{\ifdim\skip0>0pt \else\rule{0pt}{2ex}`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EdenHarder That's for adding the strut only if the previous material doesn't end with a skip (such as after a math display).